# Solutions to a set of coupled linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have the following problem. Given some vectors $\vec{w}_i\,, \vec{q} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\|\vec{w}_i\|,\|\vec{q}\|\neq 0$ and a 3x3 real matrix $M$, find the solution to the set of equations
$$
M\vec{d}_1-t_1\vec{q}+\kappa\vec{w}_1 = M \hat{e}_1 \,,\\
M\vec{d}_2-t_2\vec{q}+\kappa\vec{w}_2 = M \hat{e}_2 \,,\\
M\vec{d}_3-t_3\vec{q}+\kappa\vec{w}_3 = M \hat{e}_3 \,,
$$
for some real numbers $\kappa, t_1, t_2, t_3$ and real vectors $\vec{d}_i\in \mathbb{R}^3$. Moreover, $\hat{e}_j$ denote the unit vectors in some orthonormal system.

**Question 1:**
What are the conditions for solutions to exist?

**Question 2:**
What is the general theory for such coupled matrix equations? How do I formally write down the solutions?

**Attempt at solution/observations:**
Note that $\vec{d}_i=\hat{e}_i\,, \, \kappa=t_i=0 \, \forall i$, is a particular solution to the equations. Thus, one needs to find the solutions to the three homogeneous equations
$$
M\vec{d}_i-t_i\vec{q}+\kappa\vec{w}_i = 0 \,,
$$
for $i=1,2,3$. Then, the general solution would be the particular solution plus the solutions to the homogeneous equations.

Formally I can there write,
$$
M \vec{d}_j = \kappa\vec{w}_j- t_j \vec{q}\equiv \vec{b}_j
$$
and apply the theory of linear matrix equations.

In short, for an equation of the form $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$, solutions exist if
$$
(A A^\dagger-\mathbb{I})\vec{b} =0 \,,
$$
where $A^\dagger$ denotes the pseudoinverse of the matrix $A$. If the last equations holds, then the solutions are given by
$$
\vec{x} = A^\dagger \vec{b} - (\mathbb{I}-A^\dagger A) \vec{c} \,,
$$
where $\vec{c}$ is any real vector.

So, if I am allowed to do this trick, I can formally write the general solutions to my equations as
$$
\vec{d}_j = \hat{e}_j + M^\dagger \vec{b}_j - (\mathbb{I}-M^\dagger M) \vec{c} \,, \\
\qquad \qquad = \hat{e}_j +  \kappa M^\dagger\vec{w}_j- t_j M^\dagger \vec{q} - (\mathbb{I}-M^\dagger M) \vec{c} \,, 
$$
as long as
$$
(M M^\dagger-\mathbb{I})(\kappa\vec{w}_j- t_j \vec{q}) =0 \,.
$$
However, I am not sure if my approach is correct.

**Question 3**:
Is my formulation and approach to the problem correct?  Particularly, the equations seem to have the almost the form $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ but not quite. Any advice how to proceed?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have illustrated a feasible solution, hence the system is always consistent.

Your equations can be written as the following aug

$$\begin{bmatrix} M & 0_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 3} & -q_1 & 0_{3 \times 1} & 0_{3 \times 1} & w_1 \\ 0_{3 \times 3} & M & 0_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 1} & -q_2 & 0_{3 \times 1} & w_2 \\  0_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 3} &M & 0_{3 \times 1} &   0_{3 \times 1} & -q_3& w_2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} d_1 \\ d_2 \\ d_3 \\ t_1 \\ t_2 \\ t_3 \\ \kappa\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} Me_1 \\ Me_2 \\ Me_3\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, this reduces to a classical linear system of equations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I realized that just after posting my question... Quick question, since the matrix is 13x9 and I have demonstrated that the set of equation is consistent, then the rank-nullity theorem implies that the kernel of this big matrix is at least 4 dimensional, which also implies that my solutions have at least 4 free parameters. Right? Also, the solutions to the homogeneous problem span a 4 dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{13}$. Correct?

Comment: The matrix is $9 \times 13$, yup, at least $4$ free parameters. As for your question regarding homogeneous problem, it can be more than $4$, it's at least $4$.